# csquotes error (MakeAutoQuote)

Tags: pdftex, csquotes

After the last update of TeXLive 2018 (pretest) I get an error with csquotes' macro MakeAutoQuote:

```
\setcounter{errorcontextlines}{100}
\listfiles
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt,paper=a4,pagesize,ngerman]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\MakeAutoQuote{»}{«}

\begin{document}
ABC
\end{document}
```

The error:

```
! Package csquotes Error: Invalid argument.
```

My versions:

```
inputenc.sty    2018/04/06 v1.3b Input encoding file
babel.sty    2018/02/14 3.18 The Babel package
csquotes.sty    2018/02/11 v5.2c context-sensitive quotations (JAW)
```

I use pdfLaTeX. What is wrong here?

Comment: I'll trace thanks but in the meantime add `\UseRawInputEncoding`  as the first line of the file (see ltnews 28)

Comment: Also affects the released version of TL 2018 (even with the net installer).

Answer (score 6):

As a temporary fix, you can add

```
\makeatletter
\def\@inpenc@undefined{}
\makeatother
```

before loading `csquotes`. A fix to the package itself will be at CTAN shortly.

Comment: even though version 5.2d has been released to CTAN 2018-04-13, it still is not in TL 2018 (2018-05-03 still has 5.2c). Did the update slip through the cracks of the TL preparation?

Comment: Addendum: I just reported that to the TL list.

Comment: @JSpitzm It's not been forgotten: there is always a delay in catching up after the freeze