# How can I fix active quote mark characters on update to TL 2018?

Tags: texlive, punctuation, csquotes, active-characters, texlive-2018

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\MakeAutoQuote{‘}{’}
\MakeAutoQuote*{“}{”}
\begin{document}
  Hylo
\end{document}
```

This code works fine with pdfLaTeX from TL 2017, but causes compilation errors with TL 2018.

```
! Package csquotes Error: Invalid argument.

See the csquotes package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.15 \MakeAutoQuote{‘}{’}

? h
Only single characters with category code 12 or 13 may be
allocated as active quotes. Numbers, punctuation marks, and
characters which are part of LaTeX's syntax or reserved
for a specific purpose are invalid.
```

How can I fix my `csquotes` configuration so that my chosen active quote mark characters continue to work? All my documents use these, so simply switching to a character the package now deems acceptable is not a practical option.

`csquotes` revision history does not list any changes for version 5.2c which would affect the user interface or package behaviour - there is no entry for this update in the list of such changes. So I would assume that what worked with 5.2b should work with 5.2c. Hence, I wonder if something outside the package has changed rather than the bump from b to c itself altering the behaviour.

Comment: Mhhh, the MWE works for me on a fully updated MikTeX system on Windows, will check on TeX live and compare the package versions.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/426248/csquotes-error-makeautoquote

Comment: you can get 5.2d from ctan (it will no doubt be in texlive within a day or so)

Comment: David has already linked to the source of the problem, but let me just confirm that my MikTeX has 5.2d, where the error is fixed, and my TeX live still has 5.2c, where the bug is still present. TeX live is still catching up on the backlog of packages uploaded to CTAN between the 2018 dev freeze and release.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Aha! Thanks. It didn't occur to me this might be a general problem: I thought the issue must be with my specific choice of characters for some reason, so was looking for stuff on that. But that question concerned pretest and the answer there says the fix will be on CTAN shortly. I installed only a few hours ago, so shouldn't I have got any fix?

Comment: @moewe Oh, that makes sense. Should I delete this? The only thing my question adds is that it affects the released version of TL and not just pretest.

Comment: I don't think you should delete it, but it would probably make sense to mark it as a duplicate of the question David linked.

Comment: http://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live-commits/2018-April/date.html and http://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live-commits/2018-May/date.html make me think they are going back in time to update the missing packages. The ones updated between 9. Apr. and 15. Apr are still missing, everything else should be there. Judging from how the updating went they should get this done tonight or tomorrow night (pure speculation and no knowledge of the actual process).

Comment: Why can I only vote to close as a duplicate? Why can't I just decide this, since it is my question? After all, I'm allowed to *delete* it, which is a lot more extreme!

Comment: Mhhh, I always thought that question owners could immediately close as duplicate. But maybe that function is only available if someone else initiated the closing. You'll be delighted to hear that `csquotes` was updated this evening (http://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live-commits/2018-May/006276.html) and should be with you soon.

Comment: @moewe If I'd waited one more day :-). Good to know - thanks for all your sage advice.

Answer (score 1):

If you have many documents which load `csquotes` and/or rely on entangled custom classes and packages which do so, you may not want to rely on [Joseph Wright's preamble workaround](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/426253/). You can obviously download the updated version from CTAN manually. However, you then need to remember to remove it when TeX Live gets the updated package. To avoid that, I'm trying the following wrapper which triggers a warning on the console/log concerning the package name, but otherwise survives minimal testing.

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\ProvidesPackage{csquotes}[2018/02/11 v5.2c]
% ateb Joseph Wright: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/426253/
\def\@inpenc@undefined{}
\RequirePackage{csquotes/csquotes}
\endinput
```

This `csquotes.sty` is now in my TEXMFHOME. Hopefully, the warning will remind me to remove the file later. If not, though, this will still pull in any updated version of `csquotes` which supercedes 5.2d.